# How to evaluate PEP-508-style platform markers?

Tags: python, pip

I'd like to programmatically evaluate PEP-508-style platform markers such as `platform_system == 'Windows'`. It's not terribly challenging to implement a parser, but I assume there is one in pip. What is it called and how can I import & use it in my own script?

Comment: pip does not have a public library API, and the pip devs don't want people importing & using the code in their own scripts.  [See the documentation for more information.](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I kinda remembered that and since I'm controlling the whole environment, I'm fine with ignoring that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `pkg_resources`

`pkg_resources` (part of the [`setuptools`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/) package) provides marker evaluation function.

```
In [1]: from pkg_resources import evaluate_marker

In [2]: evaluate_marker('sys_platform == "darwin"')
Out[2]: True

In [3]: evaluate_marker('python_version > "3.7"')
Out[3]: False

In [4]: evaluate_marker('implementation_name == "cpython"')
Out[4]: True

In [5]: evaluate_marker('garbage')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/hoefling/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-2-69434540d2ec>", line 1, in <module>
    evaluate_marker('garbage')

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1372, in evaluate_marker
    raise SyntaxError(e)

  File "<string>", line unknown
SyntaxError: Invalid marker: 'garbage', parse error at 'garbage'
```

etc.

#### `packaging`

Under the hood, `pkg_resources.evaluate_marker` uses [`packaging.markers.Marker.evaluate`](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/markers.html) from the [`packaging`](https://pypi.org/project/packaging/) package, so you can use that instead:

```
In [6]: from packaging.markers import Marker

In [7]: Marker('"linux" in sys_platform').evaluate()
Out[7]: False
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Use of `pkg_resources` as a library is now deprecated in favour of either `packaging`, or the stdlib `importlib.metadata` and `importlib.resources` modules. See the warning on the documentation: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html